# What is a question mark in graphql?

Tags: graphql

What are the meanings of the various question marks here?

```
type GraphQLEnumValueDefinition = {
  name: string;
  value?: any;
  deprecationReason?: string;
  description?: ?string;
}
```

source: https://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqlenumtype

Are there other usages of question mark within graphql?

Answer (score 4):

GraphQL.js is written using [Flow](https://github.com/facebook/flow), which is a static type checker that introduces some additional syntax on top of JavaScript. The `?` indicates a [Maybe Type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/maybe/) which simply means the value is optional. So a property that has the `string` type must always be a string, while one with the `?string` type could be a string, `null` or `undefined`.

Because GraphQL.js is written in Flow, it's generated documentation includes Flow syntax. However, this syntax is unrelated to GraphQL itself. `?` is not a token in GraphQL syntax itself.

Comment: I see, this is what confused me. `String` in `gql` tagged template is nullable and `String!` non-nullable, opposite to what typed systems usually use. So anyway, what is the difference between `deprecationReason` and `description` then?